# Which is the thread id in javadumps?

Tags: java

I have a javadump file which I have to analyse. Usually thread id is specified with prefixed name `tid:` in javadumps. However in this javadumps, I dont find `tid:`.  So with what name it thread id is dumped in this specific file? Few lines in the thread dump which must contain thread id are:

```
3XMTHREADINFO      "WLMMonitorSleeper : 0" J9VMThread:0x0000000082586300, j9thread_t:0x00007FC3E0940D30, java/lang/Thread:0x00000000022D6160, state:CW, prio=5
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x2EA7, native priority:0x5, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO2            (native stack address range from:0x00007FC3AFE39000, to:0x00007FC3AFE7A000, size:0x41000)
```

(One can find similar javadumps in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-thread-dumps-ibm), which explains how to analyse threads dumps but still does not talks about where is thread id)

I am guessing the thread id must be the one following one of: `J9VMThread`, `j9thread_t` or `java/lang/Thread` in first line. But not sure. Not finding any information online including on IBM's knowledge center. If one of these is java thread id, then what are other two? Please provide the online reference explaining the same.

For details about which java version this java dumps belong to, these are some lines from the same file:

```
0SECTION       GPINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ================================
2XHOSLEVEL     OS Level         : Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
2XHCPUS        Processors -
3XHCPUARCH       Architecture   : amd64
3XHNUMCPUS       How Many       : 2
3XHNUMASUP       NUMA is either not supported or has been disabled by user
NULL           
1XHERROR2      Register dump section only produced for SIGSEGV, SIGILL or SIGFPE.
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       ENVINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1CIJAVAVERSION JRE 1.6.0 Linux amd64-64 build 20120308_104898 (pxa6460_26sr1fp1-20120309_01(SR1 FP1))
1CIVMVERSION   VM build R26_Java626_SR1_FP1_20120308_1511_B104898
1CIJITVERSION  r11_20111028_21230ifx5
1CIGCVERSION   GC - R26_Java626_SR1_FP1_20120308_1511_B104898_CMPRSS
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the thread ID? If you want to compare it with WinDbg, `native thread ID:0x2EA7` looks quite good.

Comment: But what are those `J9VMThread:0x0000000082586300, j9thread_t:0x00007FC3E0940D30, java/lang/Thread:0x00000000022D6160` ?

As I said I will be requiring them to do some analysis.

Comment: To me, those all look like 64 bit addresses. Might be locations of objects in memory. But that's just a guess. I'm not so familiar with Java yet.

Comment: Seems I'm right: [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.80.doc/diag/tools/javadump_tags_threads.html?lang=en)

Comment: That page says: *The properties on the first line are the thread name, addresses of the **JVM thread structures and of the Java thread object**, Java thread state, and Java thread priority.* While *"Java thread object"* can be considered as one with `java/lang/Thread` prefix, *"JVM thread structures"* still does not makes sense. And still I still dont understand whats that `J9VMThread` and `j9thread_t`. Between I opted to stick to `J9VMThread` as explained in the answer below. Each native thread id has single occurrence in a file. They are not used to specify the thread owning the lock.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking by analysis perspective. Currently I feel, I will be using `J9VMThread`. Because thats the id which is used else where in the same log file. For example, in `LOCKS subcomponent dump routine` of the log file, there is:

```
2LKMONINUSE      sys_mon_t:0x00007FC3BCD2D530 infl_mon_t: 0x00007FC3BCD2D5A8:
3LKMONOBJECT       org/apache/log4j/spi/RootLogger@0x00000000055E5170: Flat locked by "Thread 1" (0x000000008502FD00), entry count 1
3LKWAITERQ            Waiting to enter:
3LKWAITER                "Thread 2" (0x000000008445AF00)
3LKWAITER                "Thread 3" (0x0000000085046300)
3LKWAITER                "Thread 4" (0x000000008506CA00)
3LKWAITER                "Thread 5" (0x00000000846FB700)
```

This say `Thread 1` holds lock on `0x00000000055E5170` on which `Thread 2`,`Thread 3`,`Thread 4` and `Thread 5` have been blocked. The Thread 5's Id is `0x000000008502FD00` and lock object's id is `0x00000000055E5170`. And if you check the corresponding thread details in `THREADS subcomponent dump routine` we will find these lock object's id and thread 5's id in the following way:

```
3XMTHREADBLOCK     Blocked on: org/apache/log4j/spi/RootLogger@0x00000000055E5170 Owned by: "WebContainer : 57" (J9VMThread:0x000000008502FD00, java/lang/Thread:0x000000000B7164B0)
```

`java/lang/Thread:0x000000000B7164B0` is contained in the above line, but I did not preferred it since this id does not appear in `LOCKS subcomponent dump routine`.

Again this is mere observation. Am still unaware of which hex code means what, and how `J9VMThread`, `j9thread_t`, `java/lang/Thread` and `native thread id` have different significance internally. Still any resource / reference explaining he same will be appreciated.